# Can assignments be made as part of python list comprehension?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Can a list comprehension be used instead of the for loop below?

```
shod_l = list() # Initialize a list for empty pd.DataFrames that will be used later for merging of api query results

for q in range(len(shod_list)): #shod_list is a list containing several strings
    q = pd.DataFrame()
    shod_l.append(q)
```

Comment: Your code looks a bit dodgy as q is the loop counter and is reassigned in the loop. May work but it's not nice.

Comment: Yes, but only because the assignment is pointless; you could just `shod_l.append(pd.DataFrame())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is:

```
shod_l = [pd.DataFrame() for _ in shod_list]
```

or if using a variable `q`:

```
shod_l = [pd.DataFrame() for q in shod_list]
```

or if you're determined to use a range:

```
shod_l = [pd.DataFrame() for q in range(len(shod_list))]
```

Comment: Thanks to all. @barny yes, I do need to use range since the number of strings in shod_list can change. In any rate, very helpful! Thanks!

Comment: @Carcigenicate no, prior to running the program. I'm using the length of shod_list to  determine how many times I will need to run an api query (since the list contains different search terms that are used as part of it), and then how many empty dataframes need to be created, for putting api returned json object into each of the dataframes.

Comment: Essentially, this is what I'm after:

shod_l = [pd.DataFrame() for q in range(len(shod_list))] #thanks to @barny for that one :)

for n in range(len(shod_list)):
    shod_term = shod_list[n]
    print(f"\nNow searching: {shod_term}")
    shod_url_search = f'https://api.shodan.io/shodan/host/search?key={SHODAN_API_KEY}&query={shod_term}'
    shod_req_search = requests.get(shod_url_search) # Should really put a try/except here... later
    print(f'URL connection status: {shod_req_search.status_code}') 
    shod_results = shod_req_search.json()

do pandas stuff from here on....

Answer (score 2):

You can use list comprehension like this (since your assignment inside the loop has no effect):

```
shod_l = [pd.DataFrame() for _ in range(len(shod_list))]
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the title question, yes, it's possible using [assignment expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/). The equivalent loop would be

```
shod_l = [q := pd.DataFrame() for _ in range(len(shod_list))]
```

but as mentioned in the other answers, there's no point to binding `q`, so in this particular case, the assignment isn't needed.